# Why will my tileset not render on an HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm in the process of learning JavaScript and for my next project I wanted to create a simple RPG using a tileset game board and some simple mechanics, and while I can get most of the back-end functions to work correctly  I cannot seem to get my tileset to render properly.

I'm currently just trying to get the logic down for rendering the same image on every tile in the tileset, but when I attempt to render the tileset nothing happens. checking the console does not show any errors or problems and after searching a few tutorials I'm not seeing where my rendering would break down and not work given that I'm only attempting to render 1 single 40px x 40px grey square in each tile.

Here's a link to a gist of my code in question: https://gist.github.com/Randy-M/92c234a7a3cf8015bba6

and the raw paste of it:

```js
//Creating the game tileset map

var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvas = c.getContext('2d');

var tileImg = new Image();
tileImg.src = 'sampleTile.png';


var map = {
    tiles: [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
    ],

    tSize: 100,
    rows: 5,
    cols: 10,
    
    getTile: function(row, col) {
        return this.tiles[row][col];
    }
};

//testGrid used to verify the map.getTile function successfully loops through all array values
var testGrid = function() {
    for (r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c < map.cols; c++) {
            var tile = map.getTile(r, c);
            console.log(tile);
        }
    }
};


var renderMap = function() {
    var x = map.cols * map.tSize;
    var y = map.rows * map.tSize;
    
    for (r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c <  map.cols; c++) {
            var tile = map.getTile(r, c);
            if (tile != 0) {
                canvas.drawImage(tileImg, x, y, map.tSize, map.tSize, c * map.tSize, r * map.tSize, map.tSize, map.tSize);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

```html
HTML section is here:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="mapContainer">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="height: 720px; width: 1280px;"></canvas>
</div>


<button id="doStuff" onclick="renderMap()">draw canvas</button>


<script type="text/javascript" src="gameMap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var canvas = c.getContext('2d');
var tileImg = new Image();
tileImg.src = 'http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/b/b6/Flag_of_Japan_(bordered).png/revision/latest?cb=20100321220053';

var map = {
    tiles: [
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
        [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
        [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
        [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50]
    ],

    rows: 5,
    cols: 10,
    
    getTile: function(row, col) {
        return this.tiles[row[col]];
    }
};

var renderMap = function() {
    var size = 30;    
    var x = map.cols * size;
    var y = map.rows * size;
    for (r = 0; r < map.rows; r++) {
        for (c = 0; c <  map.cols; c++) {
            var tile = map.getTile(r, c);
            canvas.beginPath();
            canvas.drawImage(tileImg, c * size, r * size, size, size);
            canvas.stroke();
        }
    }
};
```

```html
<button id="doStuff" onclick="renderMap()">draw canvas</button>

<div id="mapContainer">
    <canvas id="canvas" style="height: 300px; width: 600px;"></canvas>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="gameMap.js"></script>
```

I replaced the image provided with the Japanese flag, as every dot now represents one tile successfully placed.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm, really looking to get an image to fill each tile. It's not just about getting a grid, I need to be able to get the logic to work to draw an image to the canvas so that I can later expand and transition to a full/true tileset.

Comment: @Randy The image now works. I changed the button location, modified the dimensions, and removed extra parameters from the `canvas.drawImage`. Is this satisfactory?

Comment: yes that's what I was looking for thank you. Other than the extra parameters on drawImage, were the dimensions on the canvas and the button placement causing the problems? It just confused the hell out of me because I wasn't seeing any errors from the console or debugger. Thanks again!

Comment: I think that the dimensions of the canvas and the button location were purely aesthetic, and that the extra parameters were the main issue.